# How to create a self-contained HTML file without the embeded files being lost?

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, quarto

When I render my Quarto script as a self-contained HTML file using `embed-resources: true` in the YAML, all embedded files (.bib and .png) are deleted. Embedding them in the HTML works fine, but since the original files are deleted, I can't render the Quarto Script correctly a second time. This only happens if I have R-Code chunks within the script (see example below).

Is this a bug or am I missing something here?

I am using R version 4.3.1 and RStudio 2023.09.0+463

This works fine, all files are included in a standalone HTML file **and** kept as files within the working directory:

```
---
bibliography: test_files/references.bib
format: 
  html:
    embed-resources: true 
---

Test @test

![TestPNG](test_files/images/test.PNG)
```

This does **not** work as intended. Files are included in a standalone HTML file **but** deleted in the working directory:

````
---
bibliography: test_files/references.bib
format: 
  html:
    embed-resources: true 
---
Test @test

![TestPNG](test_files/images/test.PNG)

```{r}
1+1
```
````

Comment: Assuming that your quarto file is called text.qmd, you should be linking to file called `references.bib` not `test_files/references.bib`. Same with images. The `_files` folders are used when you are not embedding resources.

Comment: I would like to keep all files in a separate folder, but anyway you're right! I was not aware of Quarto creating a folder with the exact same name when rendering... Just renaming the folder with all my files other than "<script_name>_files" solved the problem. Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files to be embedded may not be placed within a folder named "<script_name>_files". When rendering, Quarto will create a folder with this name and overwrite any folder named as such.

To solve the given example where the Quarto script is named test.qmd, the folder containing the files to be embedded (.bib and .png files) would need to be renamed (e.g. "testfiles").

````
---
bibliography: testfiles/references.bib
format: 
  html:
    embed-resources: true 
---
Test @test

![TestPNG](testfiles/images/test.PNG)

```{r}
1+1
```                                                                              .
````

All credits for this answer go to [nrennie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17581735/nrennie)!